# Get Types by System.Reflection: Error when I try to cast them

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I try to get the database repositories in my project by Reflection and store them in a list like shown in my code below.

All repositories implement the `IRepository<TEntity>`  interface where TEntity has to implement the `IObjectWithId` interface.

In the example below: When I try to create an instance of the repositories in the foreach- loop and store it in the list I get an error which says that `ExampleRepository` cannot be cast to `IRepository<IObjectWithId>`

```
public void GetRepositories(Entities context)
{
   this.ProcessRepositories = new List<IRepository<IObjectWithId>>();
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
   var types = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();
   types = types.Where(t => t.Name.Contains("Repository")).ToList();
   foreach (var type in types)
   {       
     this.ProcessRepositories.Add((IRepository<IObjectWithId>)Activator.CreateInstance(type,context)); //Error at this point
   }
}

//Interface for Repositories
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IObjectWithId
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
}

//Example Repository
public class ExampleRepository : BaseRepository<ExampleEntity>, IRepository<ExampleEntity>
{
    public ExampleRepository (Entities context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}

//Example Database Entity 
public class ExampleEntity : IObjectWithId
{

}


public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IObjectWithId
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }


            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new List<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone maybe help me to figure out whats wrong with my code? If I remove the generic type `<TEntity>` it works as expected. So something is wrong with that but I can't really see why.

Comment: [`IRepository<TEntity>` => `IRepository<out TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Ahh thank you! that makes sense. I edited my question and added the method to the interface. Of course it now prodcues an error because the variance isn't valid. I read the article but can't really figure out how I have to change the Get method now :/

Comment: it doesn't make sens as you can pass `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`  with `TEntity` which is `IObjectWithId` but not `ExampleEntity` ...

Comment: `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TEntity' must be invariantly valid on 'IRepository<TEntity>.Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>, string)'. 'TEntity' is covariant.` thats the full error message in VS

Comment: yes, becuse this code doesn't make sens ... without `out`  `IRepository<IObjectWithId>` has no connection with  `IRepository<ExampleEntity>` ... with `out` ... `TEntity` cannot be `in` ... because when you cast `ExampleRepository` to `IRepository<IObjectWithId>` youll could pass instance of `IObjectWithId` to `Get` method which is not `ExampleEntity`